# Personalized chat using Sails.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

Is there a way in sails.js or a tutorial that would help me build a peer to peer chat, using sockets, something like pubnub.

I am trying to implement a personalized chat feature using sails.js
What that would mean is that I have say multiple users in my application and a user can chat with another user. So if user A sends a message in user B chatbox, B(only) receives and vice-versa.

I have gone through http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/sockets , the documentation by it gives examples using the models. So I guess it is not for one-to-one chat, but for something like user list and user profile changes kind of stuff.

So I know that I need to use native socket.io code for that. What I need is that the client can open a socket for a particular channel, and then whenever user A types in to user B, that message is stored in the db, as well as written on the socket. I don't know how to get this functionality in Sails.

I can write the code in index event of the MessagesController. So I would need to compute the channel name based on the user A and user B details and write it on the socket for that channel. But I don't know how to write it to the socket for that particular channel. I hope I am clear with what I want. I found this piece of code as an example:

```
//Code For Server
var io = require("socket.io");
io.sockets.on("connection", function (sock) {
    sock.emit("welcomeMessage", { hello: "world" });
}
io.listen(80);

//Code For Client
var sock = io.connect('http://localhost');
sock.on('welcomeMessage', function (json) {
    //Handle Event Received
});
```

But it doesn't tell me, how do I write to this particular socket for channel "welcomeMessage" from any controller I want. Something like what PubNub supports (http://www.pubnub.com/) .

Comment: i found the following approach, but it doesn't look too clean, also its purely based on socket.io

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely do peer-to-peer and group chat in Sails using the model-based pubsub methods.  It's a lot easier in Sails v0.10 (`npm install sails@beta`), and there's a full example at http://github.com/balderdashy/sailsChat.  Docs for Sails v0.10 are [here](http://beta.sailsjs.org).

The trick using v0.10 is to use a combination of [*subscription contexts*](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/ModelMethods/.subscribe.html) and the [message](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/ModelMethods/.message.html) event so that only the user themselves are subscribed to their own `message` context, but they are subscribed to the `update` contexts of everyone they're in a chat room with.  That way they only get their own direct messages, but they hear about updates (i.e. name and status changes) to their friends.

To send a direct message to a `User` instance in a controller:

```
User.message(userInstance, msgData);
```

Any socket client subscribed to the `message` context of that instance will receive a `user` event with the following data object:

```
{
   id: [the user ID],
   verb: "messaged",
   data: [the data in msgData]
}
```

If you want, you can also use [low-level Sails Socket methods](http://beta.sailsjs.org/#!documentation/reference/Sockets/Sockets.html) like `join`, `leave`, `broadcast` and `emit` to make a more ad-hoc chat server, but doing it the Sails way lets you use the power of the framework to your advantage!

Comment: Hi, Is it advisable to use the beta version for a production application?

Comment: Also when is the beta version coming out with an official release?