# How to limit delivery of Sailsjs model room socket events (association security)

Tags: socket.io, sails.js

I'm using sailsjs sockets and I'm trying to find a way to add security to room events.

Basically I have a user collection with a 1-many relationship with a car collection.

I want to have my app listen to the `create` event when a user creates a new car, while making sure I'm not leaking create events by other users.

When I use `Car.subscribe(req.socket)` with

```
Car.publishCreate({
  id: 3,
  color: 'blue',
  user: 1
})
```

all users who are listening to the `Car` model room receive updates.

I know that I can specify sockets to omit with a second parameter: `Car.publishCreate( values, [socketToOmit] )`, but with many users, this becomes pretty heavyweight.

Is there a simple way to notify/limit "create" events to a specific user in a model room?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional publish events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360816/conditional-publish-events)

Answer (score 0):

In redis, there is a named Channel which supports subpub, you can push messages onto a named Channel ,such as `ToJohn`, and redirect sockets to get messages on that named Channel.

wish you luck.