# sails.io.js: subscribe to a sub-collection of records

Tags: javascript, sails.js, sails.io.js

I have the following code that queries and listens to comments. Each comment has a `page` property which stores the comment's page identifier. This identifier is the connection between the comment and its page on the website.

```
io.socket.on('comment', function(event) {
  console.log('event', event)
})

io.socket.get('/comment', {
  page: window.PAGE
}, function serverResponded (body, JWR) {
  console.log('Sails responded with: ', body)
  console.log('with headers: ', JWR.headers)
  console.log('and with status code: ', JWR.statusCode)
})
```

With the code above the browser gets informed about each new comment, *even if it does not belong to the current page.*

**How can I achieve that the browser gets informed about new comments only if the created comment's page equals the current page (which is stored in `window.PAGE`)? Is it possible with the built-in websocket functionality or do I need to write an extension?**

Answer (score 0):

You can just overwrite the `publishCreate` callback in your comment model in `api/models/comment.js`.

Take a look at the sails reference http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub/publish-create or take a look at this, where you can find an example code [Conditional publish events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24360816/conditional-publish-events).